# Changing the colors of QTableView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I want to change the colors of the Table Widget in PyQt5 in those two places, but couldn't find how:

[image: color example]

Here's my style sheet so far:

```
QTableView QHeaderView::section
    {
    background-color:rgb(48, 48, 72);
    color:white;
    }

QTableView QHeaderView::section:checked
    {
    background-color: rgb(48, 48, 72);
    color:white;
    }

QTableView QTableCornerButton::section {
    Background-color:rgb(48, 48, 72);
}

QTableView,QListView::section {
    Background-color:rgb(48, 48, 72);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QTableView QHeaderView {}
```

sets the properties of the HeaderView without sections

```
QTableView QHeaderView::section {}
```

the one of the HeaderViews sections, even of the checked ones, if no different properties for them are set. So you only need to replace the first line of your code by

```
QTableView QHeaderView, QTableView QHeaderView::section
```

the section

```
QTableView QHeaderView::section:checked {}
```

is only needed, if checked sections shall have different properties

so you can ease your code to

```
QTableView, QTableView QHeaderView,  
QTableView QHeaderView::section, QTableView QTableCornerButton:section
    {
    background-color:rgb(48, 48, 72);
    color:white;
    }
```

and only if needed

```
QTableView QVerticalHeaderView::section:checked
    {
    background-color:rgb(255, 0, 0);
    color:white;
    }
```